# how to call class methods from aspx files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using asp.net and c# in my project
I need to call my class methods in gridview component but I can't
this is my codes:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="شماره کالا"/>
    <asp:TemplateField>                    
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("smallimg") %>' Height="77" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="شرح کالا">                    
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href='/product/<%#Eval("articleID") %>/<%#Eval("postTitle") %>' target="_blank"><asp:Label ID="Label1" style="float:right;direction:rtl;text-align:right" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("postTitle") %>'></asp:Label></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="قیمت کالا">                    
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" Text='<%# Eval("price").ToString()+ " تومان" %>'></asp:Label> 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="datetime" HeaderText="تاریخ"/>
    <asp:TemplateField>                    
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" ToolTip="حذف این رکورد" 
            OnClientClick="return confirm('آیا مطمعن هستید؟')" ImageUrl="~/ucp_content/img/Trash.png" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

and I need to call ConvertMoneyFormat method in class bellow:

```
public class CLS_MoneyFormat
{

    public static string ConvertMoneyFormat(string strMoney)
    {
        string newstr=ReverseString(strMoney);
        string temp = "";
        int j=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < newstr.Length;i++ )
        {
            j++;

            temp = temp + newstr[i];

            if(j % 3==0)
            {
                temp += ",";
                j = 0;
            }
        }
            return ReverseString(temp);
    }

    public static string ReverseString(string s)
    {
        char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return new string(arr);
    }

}
```

this class is in app_code forlder
how I can call this method(ConvertMoneyFormat) in my gridview component like this : <%# ConvertMoneyFormat(Eval("price").ToString())+ " تومان" %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
<%# CLS_MoneyFormat.ConvertMoneyFormat(Eval("price").ToString())+ " تومان" %>
```

Comment: this format give this error : Error 51 Member 'CLS_MoneyFormat.ConvertMoneyFormat(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference;

Comment: could you also add namespace of this class?

Comment: do you have any parent class before the namespace?

Comment: This code working on my local, but in App_Code folder it causes some problem. For the last attempt, you can try to move your class out of App_Code folder.